# Snap on Arch Linux : Cannot create user directory

Tags: linux, arch-linux, snap

I try running termius in Arch using snap, with `snap run termius-app`, but it says :

```
2024/03/23 21:28:19.783334 cmd_run.go:1046: WARNING: cannot create user data directory: cannot create snap home dir: mkdir /home/fbdev/snap: file exists
cannot create user data directory: /home/fbdev/snap/termius-app/183: Not a directory
```

And I don't have the sssd directory.

Comment: The post [Cannot create user data directory: /home/domain/user/snap/skype/118: Permission denied](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cannot-create-user-data-directory-home-domain-user-snap-skype-118-permission-denied/16307) has this solution: "I ended up updating /etc/sssd/sssd.conf: override_homedir = /home/%d_%u (was /home/%d/%u). with added /etc/fstab line: /home/mycompany/alderben /home/mycompany_alderben none defaults,bind 0 0 Now it totally works". Try to adapt it to your case.

Comment: No. I don't have the sssd directory at all. Should I add it ?

Comment: Perhaps look for it elsewhere, if it was not added by the software then I doubt that it will be used. Or perhaps that article describes a different problem than yours.

Comment: Maybe, but in file explorer I find nothingh and with grep too.